# CSS hover transition / transform background color scale

Tags: css

I want an element's background color to change and for the element to grow slightly on hover.

The problem I have is that the background color is being applied on hover but it doesn't cover  all of the enlarged div (as transformed using scale on hover).

Please see the attached image and code.

The lighter background should be flush to the dotted border on the left.

Any ideas?

```
#recent-posts li {
transition: all .1s;
-webkit-transition: all .1s;
-moz-transition: all .1s;
transform-origin:center bottom;
-webkit-transform-origin:center bottom;
-moz-transform-origin:center bottom;
}

#recent-posts li:hover {
transform:scale(1.1);
-moz-transform:scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Makes no sense to me, the background color you're applying on hover is **transparent**! Should be logic that what you see are the borders of the sibling LI elements!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your background color has an alpha value of 0.

This makes it completely transparent so there is nothing to show of the background..

It looks like you want the hover color to be the same as the background of the container. In this case you should set the same color of the container as the `:hover` color of the `li`.

Comment: Yep, good thinking. Changed it to a solid color and it worked. Will mark as correct when it lets me. Thank you very much.